# What's the difference between eosio.token and currency.hpp?

Tags: smart-contract

What's the difference between eosio.token and currency.hpp found in the contracts/eosiolib folder?

They seem quite similar.

Answer (score 1):

eosio.token is the system contract that handles standard EOS transactions. currency.hpp is a header for a contract for creating currencies on the EOS network, like tokens for dapps. So they have roughly the same purpose, but one is a system contract and the other a regular contract that can be uploaded to any account.

Comment: That sort of answers the question, so which one is which? So if we want to develop a currency / token for an ICO, then can be used on a dapp, which one should we build?